# JFrame opens blank, runs a loop, and then displays components

Tags: java, swing, loops, user-interface

Okay, so this problem has been plaguing me for the past few days.  And before anyone comments about it, yes I have made the jframe visible and I have added all the components that I need to it.  Also,  all components are added well before the GUI is set to visible and activate() is called.

So I am trying to run a couple simeple lines of code.:

```
        g.setVisible(true);
        g.activate();
```

Simple enough. g is an object made from a class I made GUI which extends JFrame. and activate() is a method that runs an infinite loop that just does a bunch of things until the user tells it to exit.  However, when the program gets to the g.setVisible() line it opens a JFrame that is the size I specified however is completely devoid of anything.  Then it moves onto the g.activate(); which at the moment runs for a specific amount of iterations and stops. At which point it finally decides that it can go back and display my GUI.  The issue with that is that the GUI is meant to be updated by the loop from active() and keep the user in the know of what is going on.

Any help is appreciated let me know if you need more detials and thank you in advance.

Comment: can you give us the code of active() method. for added information

Comment: For better help sooner please post a [mcve] otherwise your question might get closed because it lacks it; I don't like how `"... that runs an infinite loop"` sounds, probably you want to use actionListeners for that instead of infinite loops. Also probably you want a Swing Timer and probably place your GUI inside the EDT but, I can't say what's wrong with those 2 lines of code, I need more

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use it within an actionListener unless it's possible to write my very own actionListener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many different UI frameworks, it's common for the methods you call to queue some work rather than perform it immediately.  From your description, it seems like `setVisible()` may be creating a native window but then queuing the rendering of the components.  Since this code is (presumably) running in the UI thread, it won't perform the work it queued until after running `activate()`.

Long-running tasks should never be run on the UI thread.  In Swing, you can use [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) or explicitly create a background thread.

Comment: (1+) Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Comment: @camickr You misclicked ;)

Comment: You were right I simply had to run it on another thread, which I was able to figure out with relative ease.  Thanks for your help.